# Batch error sending push: Unable to send your test message: This push token was registered with a Sender ID that doesn't match this authorization key

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I followed the Batch set up process [here](https://batch.com/doc/android/prerequisites.html).

In the logcat I got it says this:

```
W/Batch: Batch is running in dev mode (your API key is a dev one)
D/Batch: Batch.Push: Registration id: *the the registration ID It generates goes here*
```

I then assigned this push token when I created a campaign, and then it displayed this error message:

```
Unable to send your test message: This push token was registered with a Sender ID that doesn't match this authorization key.
```

The GCM Server API Key and Sender ID both seem valid.

Does anyone know what is causing this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm with the same problem. Do you find the solution?

Comment: The GCM Sender ID you put in your app code (with the Batch setGCMSenderId method) is not the same as the one you put in your web dashboard in Settings > Push settings. Which mean that Batch is unable to send push notifications to the Registration ID as the credentials you gave are for another environment / Sender ID.